# Remember touch pad status after reboot

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchpad

I have 2 different laptops, first with Linux Mint (A) and second with Xubuntu Budgie 18.04 (B). On (A) when I press FN+F7 the touch pad is toggled. When I reboot my system last setting is remembered. On (B) I have different behavior. After a reboot the touch pad is enabled. To find out how to configure it, I tried to find out which program is called, when I press the combination. I started `xev` but it doesn't register any key press, when I toggle the touch pad. But other FN keys like volume up and volume down are registered.

I'm looking for a way to store the last status of touch pad on Ubuntu Budgie so that I can toggle it with FN+F7. Is there command called when I press that combination and `xev` doesn't register it or is this function on hardware level? Is it possible to store the last status? Where would I configure it?

Comment: Usually, fn+X are BIOS related functions. They may also require OS level awareness, but I don't think it is possible to change what they are programmed to do.

Comment: @mikewhatever FN+F11 toggles WiFi. I can't change what it does but in the energy settings I can change if the last setting will be remembered after reboot. I don't want to change what these buttons do. I want to know which program is called, when I press these buttons. E.g. FN+F5 calls `pacmd` with my soundcard and `+5` so the volume goes up. I want to find out which program is called to toggle touch pad. In i3wm I can set this programs in `~/.config/i3`. Where do I do this in Ubuntu Budgie?

Comment: OK, Budgie is Gnome based, so you could try something like `gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-touchpad touchpad-enabled false` to disable touchpad. Hope that helps.

Comment: @mikewhatever In Budgie there is no such schema `org.mate.peripherals-touchpad touchpad-enabled false`. I grepped it and found `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad` and `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen`. Both don't have any keys that sound like you could disable the touchpad. Also please remember that I want to toggle the touch pad with FN+F1. I don't want to completly disable it.